# LeadHistory NewValue Field Print Different Values

Tags: apex, batch, leads, history-tracking

I wrote a batch class on LeadHistory Object. So in my sandbox when we debug the LeadHistories value then it will show the Name of the User/Queue in NewValue for ownerAssignment.Below is the Debug log Code for Sandbox Org:

```
theLeadHistory|
{"LeadId":"00Q7h000008V76TYA0",
 "Id":"0177h0870MTDSeGAQX",
 "CreatedDate":"2022-06-09T10:23:58.000Z",
 "Field":"Owner",
 "OldValue":"DummyUser",
 "NewValue":"Primary Lead Queue"}
```

But when we try to debug in Production the LeadHistories value shows RecordId of User/Group in "Newvalue" Field for OwnerAssignment. Below is the Debug log code for Production Org:

```
theLeadHistory|
    {"LeadId":"00Q88660011zb7SEAQ",
     "Id":"0178c76545ThEWiAAN",
    "CreatedDate":"2022-06-03T13:53:58.000Z",
    "Field":"ownerAssignment",
    "OldValue":"0051234YT6BUpBaAAL",
    "NewValue":"00G98600005w2mcEAA"}
```

have you guys any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you do a query on `LeadHistory`

```
SELECT Id, Owner, OldValue, NewValue FROM LeadHistory WHERE LeadId = '00Q7h000008V76TYA0'
```

you'll discover there are two rows returned

- One for the change in ID
- One for the change in Owner.Name

The SFDC Lead History (and for that matter, all other XXXHistories) suppresses the `OwnerId` change row - but it is in the database.

I suspect the reaason you are seeing one thing in PROD versus the other in sandbox has to do with the indeterminate order these are returned in your query and that you are displaying only 1 row for Field `Owner`